# How to find with sequelize considering properties of an object in an array of objects

Tags: sql, database, sequelize.js

I have an array of objects like:

```
[
  { title: 'comments-topic-4', after: '2022-08-16 18:49:09' },
  { title: 'comments-topic-3', after: '2022-08-16 19:10:05' }
]
```

Let's consider that I have a database table called `notifications` with two columns: `userGroup` and `createdAt`.

I need all notifications that has the column `userGroup` equal to 'comments-topic-4' and the column `createdAt` greater than '2022-08-16 18:49:09' (which is the first object in the array).

And I also need all notifications that has the column `userGroup` equal to 'comments-topic-3' and the column `createdAt` greater than '2022-08-16 19:10:05' (which is the second object in the array).

How to do this kind of search with Sequelize in only one request to the database?

(the solution could also be in raw SQL if not possible with Sequelize)

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @jarlh I'm using MySQL

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So, the solution for this was simple.

As I have objects, and Sequelize accepts objects as conditions, I generated one Sequelize condition object for each of my initial objects.

And then I added all this condition objects to the query.

```
const myObjects = [
  { title: 'comments-topic-4', after: '2022-08-16 18:49:09' },
  { title: 'comments-topic-3', after: '2022-08-16 19:10:05' }
]

const sequelizeConditionObjects = []

myObjects.forEach((obj) => {
    sequelizeConditionObjects.push({
        userGroup: obj.title,
        createdAt: { [Op.gt]: obj.after }
    })
})


// QUERY

await table.findAll({
    where: {
        [Op.or]: [
            ...sequelizeConditionObjects
        ]
    }
})
```